# request.method = 'post' Forbidden?

Tags: django, forms, post, get

I want to use request.POST instead of request.GET ,

```
#contact_form.html
<form action = '/contact/' method = 'post'>
    <p>Subject:<input type = 'text' name = 'subject'></p>
    <p>Your e-mail (optional): <input type = 'text' name = 'e-mail'></p>
    <p>Message:<textarea name = 'message' rows = '10' cols = '50'></textarea></p>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>
</form>


#views.py
def contact(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('subject',''):
            errors.append('Enter a subject.')
        if not request.POST.get('message',''):
            errors.append('Enter a message.')
        if not request.POST.get('email') and '@'not in request.POST['email']:
            errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
        if not errors:
            send_mail(
                    request.POST['subject'],
                    request.POST['message'],
                    request.POST.get('email', 'noreplay@example.com'),
                    ['siteowner@example.com'],
                    )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    return render_to_response('contact_form.html',{'errors':errors})
```

## then, i got this:

Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

=======================================================================

What should i do? And what exactly the difference between POST and GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is displayed by [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/) (CSRF) middleware, whose purpose is to prevent malicions website from sending data withouts your users' knowledge.

In short: you need to add `{% csrf_token %}` into your `<form>` element in the template.

What is it good for? Let's say you put this on a webpage, someone decides to spam you with bogus data, and manages to inject Javascript code that submits the form when anyone enters the page. (Or worse, in case your form allows the user to do something destructive like deleting his account.) CSFR stops that, because it ensures that only request that are sent as response to your HTML form get through.

Apart from that: there's a better way to generate and validate forms. You can use [django.forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) to make Django generate contact form that will automatically validate that user has entered subject, message text, and valid e-mail address, and display appropriate error messages if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

che's answer is definitely right, and you can also and @csrf_exempt right before you views function like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def contact(request):
```

and you should import it like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```